# Teamspeak3 download fail

Tags: server, 16.04, hostname, teamspeak

I'm trying to install the Teamspeak server on my Ubuntu server (nodesktop). I tried to install it:

```
apt-get install wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2  or: wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2
```

It told me that the hostname dl.4players.de is not working.
So, I tried to find help myself on google/youtube, but nothing worked.
Thanks kint

Comment: apt-get install works only if the installation source is in the packages. If you want to download some file through http(s) links, you can use wget.  But both do not make sense. So what you want is just:  wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2

Comment: thanks but i did this to and id did not work :-(

Comment: i can`t download the file i have no desktop so i have do download whit a downloadlink @MarkKirby

Comment: @MarkKirby i know but this is what i did and its still the problem whit      wget dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2 the awnser is still the hostname dl.4players.de is not valid

Comment: @MarkKirby i did try your awnsers multiple times but i alerady fail at the first step -> Download your package i thrust you that its working on your ubunt but in mine is  not working

Comment: @MarkKirby yes i did just as you did

Comment: @MarkKirby i woud show you mine but its in german and not on this computer (i know your`s is working)

Comment: @MarkKirby thats strange i typed: sudo apt-get install httpie it downloades normal but when i type                                                                                http dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_‌​amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.b‌​z2 it says httpie is not installed?? i dont get it anymore

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks that you try to help me i appreciate it

Comment: it says no package found @MarkKirby

Comment: i saw it changed itand it says no package found

Comment: Run this again `sudo apt-get install httpie`, give me any output, even if it is in German.

Comment: it says now that the package has not been found

Comment: E: Packet hippie kann nicht gefunden werden

Comment: 16.04.1 i loockt it up

Comment: hahaha i saw thatbutthanks so now there is: 0(zero;-)) curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dl.4players.de

Comment: are you available in 1.5 h i have to go to a meeting now if not thanks 4 all you did maby we can try later again

Comment: no i type just what you typed         see ya

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44791/discussion-on-question-by-kint-teamspeak3-download-fail).

Comment: @MarkKirby hey man i know the mistake i did well not me but my dhcp server crashed so i was not able to thanks and have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tar.bz2` cannot be installed, it is a compressed archive and must be extracted to get at the contents.

First download your package

```
wget dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2
```

Extract it

```
tar jxf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.3.tar.bz2
```

Now change to that extracted directory

```
cd ~/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64
```

Now you can run the server start script

```
./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

[image]